# create two different layout folders in an android project

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to incorporate two builds`(say build a and build b)` within a single android project. For this , I have created a `global constant boolean variable (say flag)`. Based on the`flag` value , I want the resources to be loaded for that respective build.

Is it possible to create two different `layout_a` and `layout_b` folders instead of default `layout` folder so that in activities I could simply call upon resources from required folders. or

Should be I create different files `homepage_a.xml` and `homepage_b.xml` ?

E.g

```
 in my activity class , I want to use this 
 if(flag)
    setContentView(R.layout_a.homepage);
 else
     setContentView(R.layout_b.homepage);

 instead of

 if(flag)
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage_a);
 else
   setContentView(R.layout.homepage_b);
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use `R.layout`, there's no way to use it like `R.layout%`. However I think you might be able to copy R (rename it to R1 for example and use it like that) or re-use the part for the layouts. I didn't try this one, but it looks like that your flag depends on something else, rather than Devise's density, resolution etc. methods for automatic determination of the right layout folders to use. Am I right?

Comment: R is generated automatically

Comment: @g00dy flag is nothing but a constant value. I would set it manually.Actually I have to prepare two builds of the same project I am working on. And 90% of code are similar.So I want to use same code base for both. I didn't get "copy R " ? how to do it ?

Comment: When you say 90% is the same like the other project, why not use the principlas of the Object Oriented programming and put the common parts in classes (maybe even build an external library with them) and include them in the other project too ? You're trying to complicate both the projects with the solution you have in mind ..